# Can't inflate fragments from a tab created with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I have been following the example in this page (http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/create-actionbar-in-tab-navigation-mode.html) to create 3 tabs in my application.

Currently I have it running, but when I try to modify the information displayed on the tabs (by modifying the xml file), my app crash.

I suppose this is because I'm trying to call another fragment from the tab, as you can see in here (this is suppose to be the /res/layout/fragment_a.xml in the example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Screen Design for today -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="Today HERE"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.myfont.mandi.main.MyInfoBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to inflate another Fragment on a tab. I suppose this is my problem.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!